# API Pagination - Collect all events with a maximum of 10 per API call

Tags: python, algorithm, pagination

How would I go about tackling something like this?

- Example of problem: It is known there are 100+ total results,  need to write an algorithm that retrieves all 100+ events and places them in an array/list.
- the 'after' ID will return chronologically OLDER results.
- the 'before' ID will return chronologically NEWER results.
- the 'after' / 'before' ID is passed in as a URL parameter when making the API call (i.e. `f"{api_base_url}{endpoint_path_events}?after=<hash/id>"`.

  - It is not needed to obtain the first set of results (the 10 most recent results)

My thoughts on this so far is to have a cursor file that keeps track of where the cursor is pointing and we loop through all of the pages and adds each event to an array until a condition is met that shows we are at the end.

```
# Example of problem: It is known there are 100+ total results, \
# need to write an algorithm that retrieves all 100+ events and places them in an array/list.
# the 'after' ID will return chronologically OLDER results.
# the 'before' ID will return chronologically NEWER results.
# the 'after'/'before' ID is passed in as a URL parameter when making the API call. 
    # It is not needed to obtain the first set of results (the 10 most recent results)

# EXAMPLE OF JSON BEING RETURNED

{'data': [{'event': 'example 1'},
          {'event': 'example 2'},
          {'event': 'example 3'},
          {'event': 'example 4'},
          {'event': 'example 5'},
          {'event': 'example 6'},
          {'event': 'example 7'},
          {'event': 'example 8'},
          {'event': 'example 9'},
          {'event': 'example 10'}],
 'pagination': {'after': 'a4d51ad0-eb6f-4b87-af76-471ddeecebc4',
                'before': '9057be4b-c4f8-4bfa-ba52-b5b6ff8eb39d'}}
```

```
#Pseudocode

#Attempt to load pagination cursors file, and if there is none generate one with null values:
try:
    with open('/home/ubuntu/logging-events/cursor.json') as cursor_file:
        pg_cursors = json.load(cursor_file)
except error as e:
    pg_cursors = {'cursor_before': 'null', 'cursor_after': 'null'}

def get_events():
    endpoint_events = f"{api_base_url}{endpoint_path_events}"
    r = requests.get(endpoint_events, headers=headers)
    res = r.json()
    events_list = []

    if len(res['data']) < 10:
     #Less than 10 events exist, can add them all to events_list.
     for events in res['data']:
        events_list.append(event)
     #How do I get all 100+ events?
```